Azure Synapse see how many times a table has been queried
Is there a way to see how many times a table has been queried in an Azure Synapse Dedicated pool?
I have tried to use sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests and also the logs in log analytics, but because of the type of data that we store, the 4000 char limit on the command field usually cuts off the from statement or the joins where i would expect to see that data.
outside of these 2 solutions is there a way to see table utilization stats?
I would like to be able to collect the stats from the past 90-120 days and use that to be able to make decisions on which tables are needed to be brought into our database.

Read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-pdw-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7 especially the command2 column

Not sure if this is the most efficient solution, but because log analytics doesn't collect the "command2" field and the system view only stores 10k rows I had to create a job that collects the data every (X)Hours and stores it in a table so we could eventually audit the queries on our data
